Writing to numpy array in shared memory failing past a certain size threshold, but only in IDEs
I'm trying to implement a shared numpy array for use in multiprocessing. It works fine on smaller arrays, but then failed when I tried to use a ~2.7GB numpy array (about 5.6Mx64 matrix). After a little tinkering, I found that the error occurs when writing the input matrix to the assigned shared memory, e.g. if dst is the buffered numpy array and test_matrix is the large matrix being copied over, then dst[:] = test_matrix[:] throws the following system error: Process finished with exit code 135 (interrupted by signal 7:SIGBUS).
Now here's where it gets weird. The above is with a containerized python interpreter. With a system interpreter or venv, there is still a crash, but code 139 11:SIGSEGV. Weirder still, if you run through the example below line by line in the interpreter directly, or run the script at the command-line, it works just fine (in the interpreter you can even inspect the copied matrix dst, and everything is normal).
As a control, I also tried running this in VSCode, resulting in a crash as well. So at this point, I think it might be IDE-related? Any insight would be welcome.
Here is a minimal example that successfully writes with 100k rows, and then throws the error with 1 million rows. This was run in Ubuntu 22.04, in Pycharm Professional 2024.1, using a containerized Python 3.10.12 system interpreter (no venv), a local venv, and a local system interpreter, with the results mentioned above.
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

# With 100,000 rows.
n = 100000
test_matrix = np.random.randn(n, 64)
d_size = np.dtype(test_matrix.dtype).itemsize * np.prod(test_matrix.shape)
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=d_size, name='test_shared_matrix')
# numpy array on shared memory buffer
dst = np.ndarray(shape=test_matrix.shape, dtype=test_matrix.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
dst[:] = test_matrix[:]

shm.close()
shm.unlink()

# 7: SIGBUS failure With 1,000,000 Rows
n = 1000000
test_matrix = np.random.randn(n, 64)
d_size = np.dtype(test_matrix.dtype).itemsize * np.prod(test_matrix.shape)
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=d_size, name='test_shared_matrix')
# numpy array on shared memory buffer
dst = np.ndarray(shape=test_matrix.shape, dtype=test_matrix.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
dst[:] = test_matrix[:]

shm.close()
shm.unlink()

print("I finished")


You've mentioned you're running containerized Python environment and default container limit for shared memory is 64M.
To increase it, try to increase shm_size parameter in docker compose file.

I'll try this, but even if this were the case, it still wouldn't explain the fact that the assignment works with 100,000 rows and fails with 1,000,000 when using the system interpreter (albeit with a segment fault instead of SIGBUS).

@TrentYarosevich It will work until n = 131_072 rows (64M), with more no. Try to do df -h | grep shm and see what is the max limit for /dev/shm

It would appear that in the container, you're correct, as the shared memory is shown at 64M:
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
However, at the system level, where the system interpeter also fails, I get a huge amount available:
tmpfs            48G   92M   47G   1% /dev/shm.
To be absolutely clear, this problem occurs with system interpreters and virtual environments - it is not limited to the containerized environment.
